# Windows 10 notifications come late and all at the same time

Tags: windows-10, notifications, cortana

Sometimes my notifications (from any source - Outlook, Slack, Cortana reminders...) are on time and sometimes they all come late. When they are late (sometimes by hours) they all show up together at some random time (they show one right after the other).

I read online that a corrupted profile could be the cause, but I already had this problem before and completely reset my computer. I only did the reset a couple of weeks ago and now I'm seeing this problem again (since it's not consistent I can't tell how long this has been happening).

This is particularly annoying with Cortana reminders, as they are pretty much useless to me if they don't show up on time.

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: I see this on one of my Windows 10 boxes (the one managed at my workplace) but not on the other (my personal machine). I'm not sure of the difference but I too find it frustrating.

Comment: You're not alone. Someone suggested disabling Cortana via group policy but it's already disabled in my case. Very frustrating.